# .htaccess 301 redirect not working on WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect `domain.com/our-team/team-member/` to `domain.com/about/`

Here is the .htaccess code that I'm using:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/our-team/team-member(.*) ^/about/$1`

However what happens with that code is that I'm redirected to `http://domain.com/about/team-member/`, which is essentially 404 page.

I've tried numerous variations on this htaccess rule with no luck as of yet.

Could something else be at play here? Could this be related to the way WordPress works, or something going on with the shared Go Daddy hosting environment the site is hosted in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bad target URL starting with `^`. Also it is better not to mix `mod_alias` rules i.e. `RedirectMatch` with other `mod_rewrite` rules of WP. Use this rule just below `RewriteBase` line in your main WP htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^our-team/team-member(/.*)?$ /about$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However it's still not working for me. I get the same incorrect URL when redirected. I've tried adding the line immediately below the `RewriteBase` line, as well as at the bottom of my .htaccess file. I've tried so many different things for this redirect, I'm beginning to think maybe the problem lies somewhere else?

Comment: Just before RewriteBase is correct. Also make sure to test it on a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: Thank you! I believe the problem was that I had put this line of code _after_ `RewriteBase` when it actually needed to come before. The redirect is now working properly.

Comment: it works for me when it's after RewriteBase. But I use an absolute path.

Comment: Hi, can you explain what is (/.*)?$

Comment: That match an optional substring of any length that has `/` at the start.